# Uppercase alias in git

Tags: git, alias

I'm trying to create an alias for both `git s` and `git S` to run `git status`.  Issue is git seems to be always forcing my alias to lowercase.  Is there a way around this?

Below I tried to alias uppercase `K` to status, but it was changed to lowercase `k`

```
server[18]:/.../src$ git S
git: 'S' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean one of these?
        d
        l
        s
server[19]:/.../src$ git config --global alias.K status
server[20]:/.../src$ git S
git: 'S' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean one of these?
        d
        k
        l
        s
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_configuration_file) does mention that:

> The variable names are case-insensitive, allow only alphanumeric characters and -, and must start with an alphabetic character

So it is unlikely that you can define *two* aliases for the same letter.

> It looks like capital aliases are not valid, is there a workaround for that?

Yes, instead of defining aliases, put in your $PATH (if you are not on Windows) regular bash scripts (without extension) called `git-s` and `git-S`: any script called `git-xxx` can be called as `git xxx`.

Comment: I'm not trying to define 2 aliases for the same letter.  I want the tag to be case-insensitive.  It doesn't appear that is true.  If you look at my code above, I'm trying to use `git S` as `git s`, but it's saying 'S' is not defined.  And when I defined 'K' it was converted to 'k', and 'K' was not valid.  It looks like capital aliases are not valid, is there a workaround for that?